# Trying to automate git clone operation in script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, dialog

I'm trying to automate the the git clone process process by creating dialog shell script. current i have bash shell script, and it works fine

```
cd /usr/src/;
       if [ ! -d "example" ]; then
           git clone https://example.git
       fi
     cd example;
     docker build -t "example:latest" .;
       cd /usr/src/;
      docker run -d -t --memory="512m" -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --env="NODE_CONFIG_DIR=/usr/local/src/example/config" --env="HOST_TOKEN=$HOST
```

but when i insert this to dialog shell script it won't work
how to do same process in dialog shell using  dialog --gauge

Comment: You can specify your requirement clearly and tell us what you have tried, the code in its current form is not clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Inian please check now